# PHP convert parsed and modified content into manageable array

Tags: php, arrays, object

The structure of the object after trimming and modifying looks like this:

```
{"key1": {
    "key": value,
    "key": value,
    "key": [
        {
            "key": value,
            "key": value,
            "key": value
        },{
            "key": value,
            "key": value
        }],
    "key": value
},
"key2": {
    "key": value,
    "key": value,
    "key": [
        {
            "key": value,
            "key": value,
            "key": value
        },{
            "key": value,
            "key": value
        }],
    "key": value
},
"key3": {
    "key": value,
    "key": value,
    "key": [
        {
            "key": value,
            "key": value,
            "key": value
        },{
            "key": value,
            "key": value
        }],
    "key": value
}}
```

How can I convert this into a manageable array where I can get keys, go into the keys and get data?  Using `is_array` to check if it is already an array, of course it isn't.

If there are more modifications which need to be made to make it easier to turn into an array, I can `substr` more.  I mainly need the data inside key1, key2, key3.

Casting an array on the variable and doing a foreach key/value just gives me a "0" as a key...so I think I need to go line by line and make it into an array?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If input variable is a in JSON format you can use this:

```
    var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Comment: What I have done so far is trim and format it to have even enclosing braces.  Originally it was a javascript var.  Doing a `foreach ($data as $key => $value)` doesn't give me anything because I think it's not in the proper array format.

Comment: You can convert variable in javascript to JSON and then you can parse it to `json_decode()`

Comment: Problem is I am not in control of the javascript.  The format is AS IS when it's being given to me...

Comment: Please try putting your data into online json validator. What's the output?

Comment: You're correct.  I was making it too difficult.  It was already in json format.  Thanks!